# SVG text above rect strange layout

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

I try to make SVG text (wrapped in `<text>` of course) place on SVG `<rect>`.

And I want to make it look like text centered in my rect.

But strange thing I got there, it looks not like I assumed.

It looks like this

[image]

When I assumed it gonna be look like that

[image]

Whats wrong with that?

First I tought that equal `x` and `y` in `<text>` and `<rect>` will work, but it was like in picture below

[image]

I tought that `y="50%"` in text will force text to ancor somewhere in the middle. But I can achieve in only at `y="80%"` as you can see.

Original markup is here

```html
<svg height="500" width="500" class="ng-scope">

  <svg height="50" width="393.703125" y="0">

    <g>
      <rect x="0" y="0" height="50" width="393.703125" style="fill: #A8A8A8">
      </rect>
      <text font-family="Airal" font-size="45" x="0" y="50%" inline-size="200">
        TEST TEXT IN SVG
      </text>
    </g>
  </svg>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `y` property is per default applied to the text **bottom line** - so there is a difference between the y-position of a text and the y-position of lines, rectangles, or other shapes.

You can use the `alignment-baseline` property e.g. with `middle` to achieve better results. [Here's the w3c description](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#AlignmentBaselineProperty) with many more options.

```html
<svg height="500" width="500" class="ng-scope">

  <svg height="50" width="393.703125" y="0">

    <g>
      <rect x="0" y="0" height="50" width="393.703125" style="fill: #A8A8A8">
      </rect>
      <text font-family="Airal" font-size="45" x="0" y="50%" inline-size="200" alignment-baseline="middle">
        TEST TEXT IN SVG
      </text>
    </g>
  </svg>

</svg>
```

Comment: Oh, wow, nice answer! Actually I never tried to use svg before. Thanks for the link also :)

Answer (score 2):

add viewBox. Again i am not expert at svg , have done just some work but this may work.

```html
<svg height="500" width="500" class="ng-scope">

  <svg height="50" width="393.703125" y="0" viewBox="0 0 90 90">

    <g>
      <rect x="0" y="0" height="50" width="393.703125" style="fill: #A8A8A8" >
      </rect>
      <text font-family="Airal" font-size="45" x="0" y="50%" inline-size="200">
        TEST TEXT IN SVG
      </text>
    </g>
  </svg>

</svg>
```